# Set up Event upon Barcode Scan in Excel User Form

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create an event upon scanning a barcode in my UserForm in excel.

What I would like to happen is when the form receives the line of information from the scan an event happens based on what it receives.

I tried to create an event with

```
if EnterKeyBehavior = True Then
   Msgbox "It Worked!"
End If
```

but that did not work.

Comment: Check the setup on the barcode scanner.  Most have multiple options for which character gets passed after the barcode is successfully scanned.  The most common is to pass in a TAB.

Comment: Are you scanning into a textbox?

Comment: @TimWilliams Yes does it need to be a different thing?

Comment: If you have a scanner setup to pass TAB and you are scanning into a textbox then you could respond to the 'Exit' event of the textbox to do whatever is needed.

Comment: use the textbox change events